# Patch 5994 is causing module Adminhtml 404 Status Error

Tags: module, adminhtml, ce-1.8.1.0, patches

I applied the Patch 5994 the other day and it has caused the admin section of a module I build to throw a 404. Has anyone else had this. The module is fine on the frontend though.

It's Magento 1.8.1.0 and having rolled back through my commits it's definitely Patch 5994 where everything went wrong.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

Below is my config.xml file for the module which I suspect holds the answer:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Playzone>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Playzone>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <playzone>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Playzone</module>
                    <frontName>playzone</frontName>
                </args>
            </playzone>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <playzone>
                    <file>playzone.xml</file>
                </playzone>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <playzone>
                    <file>playzone.xml</file>
                </playzone>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <playzone>
                            <title>Play Zone</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </playzone>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <menu>
            <cms>
                <children>
                    <playzone_adminform module="playzone">
                        <title>Play Zone</title>
                        <children>
                            <activity module="playzone">
                                <title>Activities</title>
                                <action>playzone/adminhtml_activity</action>
                            </activity>
                            <category module="playzone">
                                <title>Categories</title>
                                <action>playzone/adminhtml_category</action>
                            </category>
                            <competition module="playzone">
                                <title>Competitions</title>
                                <action>playzone/adminhtml_competition</action>
                            </competition>
                        </children>
                    </playzone_adminform>
                </children>
            </cms>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <playzone>
                <class>Company_Playzone_Helper</class>
            </playzone>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <playzone>
                <class>Company_Playzone_Block</class>
            </playzone>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <playzone>
                <class>Company_Playzone_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>playzone_resource</resourceModel>
            </playzone>
            <playzone_resource>
                <class>Company_Playzone_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <activity>
                        <table>playzone_activity</table>
                    </activity>
                    <category>
                        <table>playzone_category</table>
                    </category>
                    <competition>
                        <table>playzone_competition</table>
                    </competition>
                </entities>
            </playzone_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <playzone_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Playzone</module>
                    <class>Company_Playzone_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </playzone_setup>
            <playzone_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </playzone_write>
            <playzone_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </playzone_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Off to module testing for breakages...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the new security feature in full effect as [outlined by Cyrill Schumacher](https://twitter.com/SchumacherFM/status/599031440584495104). He also was so kind as to [provide the fix](https://twitter.com/SchumacherFM/status/599120967835656192):

> controller must extend admin html controller and config.xml routers
>   section must also use admin.

There is a very good explanation at *Solving Magento* – [Magento Routers: a Look under the Hood](http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-routers-a-look-under-the-hood/).

If you need a custom router name, the section that needs to be added should look like this:

```
<config>
    ...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <playzone>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Limesharp_Playzone</module>
                    <frontName>playzone</frontName>
                </args>
            </playzone>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    ...
</config>
```

<strike>It is more common to extend the router configuration though:</strike>

**Update**: As of Magento CE 1.9.2.2, the previous example is only applicable to frontend routes. Extending the router configuration is the way to go:

```
<config>
    ...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Limesharp_Playzone before="Mage_Adminhtml">Limesharp_Playzone_Adminhtml</Limesharp_Playzone>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    ...
</config>
```

Comment: So, it's a red warning flag for Modules that haven't been created securely.